# Boot Windows Installation as VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

I currently have multiple windows installations, sometimes I need to see some program configuration from my other installation and I have to reboot. I parallel for mac you can actually boot your windows installation as if it were a VM from OS X. Is there any way in windows to just boot my other windows installation as a VM rather than have to restart in to the other installation?

Comment: You can try to boot the drive using a VirtualBox VM with "Raw Hard Disk Access." Every single warning about backing up data and potential loss of data are in effect though. This may cause significant problems. Typically if you give a VM direct HD access, you install an OS through the VM onto that disk, and you don't boot a physical PC with that disk. I don't know of any software for Windows that is comparable to the solution you mention for Mac. There is no guarantee that any disk you boot a physical PC from will boot as a VM disk, and vice versa. If something exists, I'm all ears.